# Creating a func for better query searching

Tags: c#, func

I am very very new to writing c# using delegates and funcs. Literally watched a pluralsite video an hour ago.

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to write a flexible method for building up a Where clause in my mvc application using EF and IQueryable

To try explain I thought I would write a small example of what I am trying to do as a console application

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var city1 = new ArgsSearch() {Address = "city1"};
        var city2 = new ArgsSearch() { Address = "city2" };
        var city1Dealers = DummyDealers().Where(GenerateSearchCriteria<CarDealer>(city1)).ToList();
        var city2Dealers = DummyDealers().Where(GenerateSearchCriteria<CarDealer>(city2)).ToList();

        foreach (var carDealer in city1Dealers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(carDealer.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________________________");

        foreach (var carDealer in city2Dealers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(carDealer.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("_______________________________________");
    }

    public static List<CarDealer> DummyDealers()
    {
        return new List<CarDealer>()
        {
            new CarDealer() {Address = "city1", Id = 1, Name = "name1"},
            new CarDealer() {Address = "city1", Id = 2, Name = "name2"},
            new CarDealer() {Address = "city2", Id = 3, Name = "name3"},
            new CarDealer() {Address = "city2", Id = 4, Name = "name4"}
        };
    }


    public static Func<TSearch, bool> GenerateSearchCriteria<TSearch>(ArgsSearch args) where TSearch : IBaseModel
    {

        if (this.GetType() == typeof(CarModel))
        {
            //return
            return e => e.Name == args.Name;// && e.Cost == args.Cost;
        }
        if (GetType() == typeof(CarDealer))
        {
            return e => e.Name == args.Name;// && e.Address == args.Address;
        }
        return e => e.Name==args.Name;

    }


    public class ArgsSearch
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    }
```

Am I going down the right track? How do I know that TSearch is either CarModel or CarDealer? allowing my custom search values to be applied.

Thanks for any suggestions and any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Instead of this.GetType use typeof(TSearch)

Comment: Thanks Gusman. One step closer :) What about gaining access to the properties of TSearch?

Comment: You could use (e as CarModel).Name in the lambda instead. On a side note, I'd recommend a different approach: making a different method for each different type (CarModel, CarDealer), and instead of making it return a Func, simply have the method definition be:
public bool IsEquivalent(CarModel model, ArgsSearch args) {}. Since you are checking for types in the method anyway, this way seems cleaner. Then, you can pass this method directly into the query as it fits the delegate type.

Comment: Two options, direct cast or reflection, with direct cast you will program each possible comparation but its faster, with reflection you will program a genéric method but its slower.

Comment: If you want to use it with `IQueryable<T>` you'll want to return an `Expression<Func<TSearch, bool>>` from your GenerateSearchCriteria method.

Comment: Thanks for tip RobH I will take a read up on what Expression does differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast:

(warning: ugly code ahead)

```
    if (typeof(TSearch) == typeof(CarModel))
    {
        //return
        return e => e.Name == args.Name && ((CarModel)(object)e).Cost == args.Cost;
    }
    if (typeof(TSearch) == typeof(CarDealer))
    {
        return e => e.Name == args.Name && ((CarDealer)(object)e).Address == args.Address;
    }
    return e => e.Name==args.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas I do get an error however "Cannot convert type 'TSearch' to 'CarFuncPlay.Program.CarDealer'"

Comment: You'll have to cast with `as`. E.g. `(e as CarDealer)`.

Comment: @DiverDan, ah, yes, because the compiler can't make sure that the cast is valid, so you need to fool it by casting to `object` first... I updated my answer.